# How to add input field using php

Tags: php, ajax

AJAX CALL

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax( {
                // <!--insert.php calls the PHP file-->
                url: "inputbill.php",
                method: "post",
                data: $("form").serialize(),
                dataType: "text",
                success: function(strMessage) {
                        $("#user_bill").text(strMessage);
                }
            });
        });
```

inputbill.php

```
<?php
 include_once 'includes/dbh.inc.php';
 $conn= mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","slashbill");
 $q="SELECT member1 FROM member;"; 
 $q_r=mysqli_query($conn,$q);
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($q_r)){
   echo $row['member1'];
   echo '<input type="number" id="value[]" name="paid[]" value="0" min="0">'; 
 }
?>
```

OUTPUT

```
NITISH<input type="number" id="value[]" name="paid[]" value="0" min="0">RAM<input type="number" id="value[]" name="paid[]" value="0" min="0">SHYAM<input type="number" id="value[]" name="paid[]" value="0" min="0">RITIKA<input type="number" id="value[]" name="paid[]" value="0" min="0">ROMEO<input type="number" id="value[]" name="paid[]" value="0" min="0">JULIET<input type="number" id="value[]" name="paid[]" value="0" min="0">
```

The Input Field is not being printed instead the code is being printed.

Or is there any other way to print the input field along with names retrieved from the database

Comment: according to your code its giving you right op .. what do you want to achieve ?

Comment: input field, I need e.g. NAME [    input field     ], instead of the code <input type="number" id="value[]" name="paid[]" value="0" min="0">

Comment: currently your return type for ajax call is `dataType: "text"` thats the reason its not working .. either remove this line or try with `dataType : 'html'`

Comment: did both but the same output comes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on this line

```
$("#user_bill").text(strMessage);
```

your appending a text inside `#user_bill` element, if you change it to

```
$("#user_bill").html(strMessage);
```

which basically tell to update the HTML inside that element, so it's going to replace **everything** with `strMessage` content